# Joda-time: convert jodaTime with timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

Please help me with this case:

1. pick a date from front-end, like 3/8/2016 05:53:00
2. A user's timeZone is GMT-08:00, plus with 8 hours, save it to DB as 3/8/2016 13:53:00
3. B user's timeZone is GMT-10:00, plus with 10 hours, save it to DB as 3/8/2016 15:53:00
4. A and will see 3/8/2016 05:53:00 on page after we convert the date from Database.

I think we can write a util to convert datetime, plus or minus it.
Is there a stand way to implement it?

Comment: Set the timezone when parsing the userinput and also set the timezone you want to store the date in. Then just write it to the database. Upon reading and formatting for output you again apply the user's timezone. Since you're working with JodaTime refer to the documentation on how to map the dates to either `java.util.date` or directly to the database and how to apply a timezone to parsers, formatters and the date itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick the date and add the times one for the conversion.
All the Joda timezones are [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html):

## Example:

```
final DateTime dt = new DateTime();
// translate to Honolulu local time
final DateTime dtVancouver = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+8"));
final DateTime dtHonolulu = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+10"));
System.out.println(dt);
System.out.println(dtVancouver);
System.out.println(dtHonolulu);
```